# I'm trying to parse an XML fragment with Linq to XML

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, xml-parsing

I trying to parse the "message" element out of the following XML fragment using Linq to XML but for some reason it isn't working:

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code/>
    <message xml:lang="en-US">Bad Request - Error in query syntax.</message>
</error>
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: Provide your source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well how does your code look, which is the result you expect, which one do you get, if you get an error post the exact error message. The fragment has a namespace so make sure when selecting elements you do something like this:

```
XElement error = XElement.Parse(fragment); 
XNamespace df = error.Name.Namespace; 
XElement msg = error.Element(df + "message");.
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  Basically, you have to use the default namespace as shown:

```
        var element = XElement.Parse(...);

        var ns = element.GetDefaultNamespace();

        var message = element.Element(ns + "message").Value;
```